# Resources and advice for starting a new company

Tags: startup, entrepreneurship

I am a senior undergraduate, a former intern of a web application startup and now working as a freelancer. After an internship of a few months, I have gained some experience about how things work at a startup. After leaving the job, I wanted to learn about machine learning and find an internship or any other job in that industry.

However, I have received advice from a couple of my connections who have been working in high roles in big companies that I should go towards entrepreneurship and start my own company. I am looking forward to join online meetups of local startups but since it's online there is very little engagement except chat although I may be able to meet someone personally to get advice from them, but I am not sure what questions I would be asking them. I searched through stack-exchange and found [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72967/what-should-i-know-before-starting-a-software-company/198059?r=SearchResults#198059) and [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/89048/when-and-how-a-programmer-should-start-own-business) but they are quite general and not related to Machine Learning and are pretty old (there's great advice in them though).

I have very limited time to decide which path to follow but as mentioned my interest is towards my own business. I would appreciate if anyone could guide me how to start my journey.

Comment: They have a somewhat wrong idea of what i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one and only one reason for a company to exist - that it provides goods or a service to customers. Without customers, I starved. When I found customers, I could get paid.

Your post suggests that you see starting your own company as a way to learn Machine Learning. It is very hard to find customers when you don't have the expertise to offer them. A better route would be to get a job with a company where you can learn about Machine Learning and later start your own company offering that to other customers.

In some ways by being a freelancer, you have already started your own company. You are providing a service to those customers with the skills you already have. It is very rare to find a client who will pay for you to learn anything new. As a freelancer, you will need to learn any new skills on your own time. (For example, I'm building a product "on spec." on a new platform for me and learning new technologies on my own dime.) When I'm done, I will be able to advertise that I have experience with those new technologies and get new customers who want them.

Comment: I really appreciate your response! I agree with most of your points. I'm sorry i did not state my question clearly i forgot to mention that i have an year ahead to learn everything about both of them and thanks for advice on getting a job but it's very hard getting one there days especially without experience

Comment: @adnanahmed Landing a job without experience is probably much easier than getting clients without experience...